# How to format number correctly in a calculator app (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mathjs

This is my first time posting in SO, and I need help formatting numbers correctly in a calculator app that I've made using ReactJS.

Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1cj5qw?file=src%2FInput.js) on StackBlitz.

Now, I want to achieve the formatting effect after numbers are pressed and shown in the display and arithmetic signs are added, especially when multiple arithmetics are used.

To illustrate my point, below is a sample of the current display:

`123456 + 7890123 * 11111`

And what I want to achieve is this:

`123,456 + 7,890,123 * 11,111`

I could only do this when displaying the result using the `toLocaleString()` function. Even then, if I pressed number/numbers and then clicking the result button twice, it will be crashed (as the display contains a comma, and the evaluation function will not process it properly).

Hopefully, someone can point me out in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful to you. https://blog.usejournal.com/everything-react-first-app-188b33a880ca

Comment: These one helps you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript . At first i think that you can display comma formatted numbers to screen in another state and your evaluate process happens in different state.

Comment: Hi there Yushan, the blog link does not contain formatting solutions.

Comment: Deniz, yeap I thats the most optimal way of doing it. Will try it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Fix

You can remove `','` before evaluating the result.
Change line 65 of Input.js to

```js
setDisplay(evaluate(display.replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString());
```

### Better Solution

Keep separate variables for **Internal logical state** and **External Display state**, where the former is valid for code and the latter is its visual representation.

You can achieve this by useEffect like this

```js
/* --- Display.js --- */
const Display = ({ display }) => {
  const [printValue, setPrintValue] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    setPrintValue(`${display}`.replace(/[0-9]+/g, num => (+num).toLocaleString()))
  }, [display])
  return (
    <StyledDisplay>
      {' '}
      <span>{printValue}</span>{' '}
    </StyledDisplay>
  );
};
```

Also, in `Input.js`, update line 65 in `handleResult` to

```js
setDisplay(evaluate(display));
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works amazingly! Appreciate it Avinash.

Comment: @iamkyo Please vote or accept the answer which you find helpful. That helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situations, I like to use regex. Here what you can do is to use a regex that matches 3 digits and add the comma as wanted. To simplify the regex I usually reverse the string:

```js
const original = "123456 / 98765 * 22222"

function format(str) {
  const reversed = str.split('').reverse().join('')
  const formatted = reversed.replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/gm, `$1,`)
  return formatted.split('').reverse().join('')
}
console.log('original string : ', original)
console.log('result string : ',format(original))
```

You can use this function in your `Display` component, just before injecting the `display` prop like this

```
function format(str){
    const reversed = str.split('').reverse().join('')
    const formatted = reversed.replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/gm, `$1,`)
    return formatted.split('').reverse().join('')
}
const Display = ({ display }) => {
  return (
    <StyledDisplay>
      {' '}
      <span>{format(display)}</span>{' '}
    </StyledDisplay>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great too! Though I'm curious for the need to reverse the array, wouldn't work just fine if I don't use it?

Comment: If you don't reverse, the regex become more complex as you actually need to determine wether or not you need a separator. By reversing you just need to know how many digits are in a group `(\d{3}))`and if there are still at least one digits after the group `(?=\d)`. It should be possible to do it without reversing but I didn't search too much

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Appreciate the explanation.